# Show spinner and disable page while waiting for ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a project in which I use MVC C#, with Bootstrap and FontAwesome.

My objective is to show a spinner and disable the page while waiting for an ajax request.

So far, I have successfully acomplished this goal with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id='ajax_loader' style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; display: none;">
    <img src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function blablabla() {
            //show spinner, disable page
            var modal = $('<div>').dialog({ modal: true });
            modal.dialog('widget').hide();
            $('#ajax_loader').show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: url,
                success: function (result) {
                   alert("success! " + result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("error!" + result);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    //back to normal!
                    $('#ajax_loader').hide();
                    modal.dialog('close');
                }
            });
        }
```

Now, **this code works**, I have the page disabled and I show a spinner. 
**However**, this spinner is also grayed out, and I do not want that to happen.

How can I prevent this bug ?

Comment: Move the spinner outside of `#ajax_loader`

Comment: I don't get it. Where do I put it then? The `div#ajax_loader` **is the spinner**

Comment: How did you grey out the page? by applying styles to `body`?

Comment: I grey out the page by using the modal and hiding. It is a solution I took from another StackOverlfow question :D

Comment: try giving z-index for #ajax_loader

Comment: Sorry my English is bad and i don't know what do you mean with "the spinner is grayed out". Do you mean your spinner looks like disabled as well? If is that, put a z-index to #ajax_loader

Comment: try with `<div id='ajax_loader' style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; display: none;z-index:999;">`

Comment: Using the z-index still doesn't work =( Perhaps I should try another method for disabling the page?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix try with `position: absolute`. while loader is there inspect element and apply `z-index` and increase in value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, after a long search, I came up with my own solution:

This is the modal with the spinning wheel, or progress bar, or anything you want to. It is in a partial file called "_WaitModal"

```
<div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Please Wait</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="ajax_loader">
            <img src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use `@Html.Partial("_WaitModal")` in the view to integrate it (but not show it).

Then, when I want to show it, I use:

```
$('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal();
```

and to hide it:

```
$('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
```

I hope this helps other people as well!

Comment: @Suma The solution uses Bootstrap which includes a modal feature. The OP mentioned their project uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 6):

try this..

**Html**

```
<button>Click Me</button>
<div class="ajax_loader hidden"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
.ajax_loader{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.ajax_loader i{
    position:absolute;    
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

**Script**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".hidden").show();
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4oayfuxa/)

Comment: Interesting solution, however, it does not disable select2 dropbown boxes =(

Comment: sorry I cant get you?? you mean still the select box is not hiding??? if so try to add "z-index:1" to the class ".ajax_loader"

Comment: It does disable select dropdown without z-index in the current FF and Chrome version.