# MVC on submit showing and hiding spinner

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**MVC Form**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Student", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "studentForm" }))
```

**Jquery**

```
 $("#studentForm").submit(function (e) {
           // showing loading  spinner here
 });
```

Here how to show and hide the loading spinner? Is there any success and failure callbacks for the above jquery submit event. Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30196610/4588756

Comment: I think its not a duplicate. I want to know success and failure events for jquery submit event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form that way, that cause a complete page callback to server. so there is no chance to show and hide a spinner. if you want async callback it is better to use $.ajax so you have more control on process life cycle.
also there is a nice plugin you can use more close to your own way: https://github.com/claviska/jquery-ajaxSubmit

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
$("#StudentForm").submit(function (event) {
            var isValid = $('#StudentForm').valid();
            if (isValid) {
                // Showing Spinner Here
            }
        });
```

Thanks!